# How do I maintain the state of a hover on mouse out?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying a transition where a line becomes a long rectangle. I want to make it so that when the transition finishes, the final state remains in place even when the mouse is not hovered on it.

This is my current code:

```css
#line {
    width: 300px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    transition: height 2s;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
}

#line:hover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="line"></div>
```

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate question, but while I find a good target, the answer is `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

Comment: @TylerH That's for an animation. Does it work for transitions too?

Comment: @GolezTrol I think it does, though I don't know about on `:hover`. Anyway it looks like OP isn't actually dealing with animations here; I'll edit the question.

Comment: @GolezTrol Hey, I have a small follow-up question. What if, instead of hovering my mouse, I want the animation to start after it is clicked?

Comment: There is no relationship between maintaining the final state of an animation and keeping a transitioned hover state. So, I would answer to @GolezTrol that no, it won't work in this scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is to add a small script that adds a class. The class remains after unhovering:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('line').addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('line').classList.add('activated');
  });
});
```

```css
#line {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  transition: height 2s;
  -webkit-transition: height 2s;
}
#line.activated{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="line"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hey, this seemed to be the solution I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Same code, but using `click` instead of `mouseover` event.

Comment: It's a bit hard to click on a single pixel line, though. Hovering is easier. If you want to make it clickable, you should consider making it a couple of pixels high to start with.

Comment: yeah, i'll consider that

Comment: There is a solution using only CSS: make the transition time in the normal state very long, and the transition time in the hover state the 2 s that you want.

Comment: @vals Dirty, but I like the idea. :) Can you make it into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way to get this effect only with CSS: set the transition-delay on the element to a huge value. and set it to 0 on the hover state

When you hover, the element changes to the hover state, and this way the transition is immediate.

When you un-hover, there will a 9999s delay before it begins (well, not really **for ever**, but nobody will notice)

```css
#line {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s 9999s;
  transition: height 1s 9999s;
}
#line:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="line"></div>
</body>
```